# How to use the functionality of the new Data.DBXOdbc unit included in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Tags: sqlite, connection, odbc, dbexpress, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I used to work with Delphi 2007 and I was able to connect to many different database mgmt. systems using the Open source dbExpress drivers of Vadim V. Lopushanskiy. Now I work with 10.2 Tokyo. I'm happy that I can connect to Access again after reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924055/setup-an-odbc-connection-to-a-ms-access-db-under-data-explorer-in-xe2-enterprise#_=_). And to SQL Server, but I don't use it ;-)

I'm experiencing problems though esp. when trying to connect to Oracle and Sqlite3 in the kind of flexible way I'm used to. Let me focus on the problems I have with connecting to Sqlite. I use the SQLite ODBC Driver developed by Christian Werner. No success, i.e. I get this as error: 'unsupported info option 131'. It's unfortunate that there's so little documentation available how to use the functionality of the new Data.DBXOdbc unit. Hopefully Embarcadero will do something about this.

Below my code, from a DataModule unit with a TSQLConnection on it which is assigned to TCustomConnection called FDatabase. This is the code for connecting to Sqlite:

```
with (FDatabase As TSQLConnection) do
begin
  VendorLib := 'sqlite3odbc.dll';
  Params.Values['TRIMCHAR'] := 'True';     // 'Trim Char'
end;
if aUseDsn then
  ConnStr := 'DSN=' + aDbxProviderStr + ';'
else
begin
  // Work the database qualifier into a connection string.
  // Assume that aDbxProviderStr contains that database qualifier.
  Connstr := 'DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=';
  Connstr := Connstr + aDbxProviderStr + ';';
end;
if (aUsername <> '') and  (aPassword <> '') then
begin
  ConnStr := ConnStr + 'UID=' + aUsername + ';PWD=' + aPassword + ';';
end;
with (FDatabase As TSQLConnection) do
begin
  Params.Values[DATABASENAME_KEY]  := '?';
  Params.Values[CONNECTION_STRING] := ConnStr + 'coEnableUnicode=0;';
end;
(FDatabase As TSQLConnection).Open;
```

I hope somebody out there can show us how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's apparently possible to use a TSQLConnection object for connecting to different databases, e.g. Sqlite, MS-Access or Oracle. Of course one at the time. You need to assign all the properties mentioned in the dbxconnections.ini file to the TSQLConnection object, starting with the DriverName property. This ini file can be found in folder C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\dbExpress\19.0

I was hoping that I could connect to the 3 mentioned database management systems (dbms) via Odbc, but I gave up. After all, the error 'unsupported info option 131' is from the ODBC driver and this error is difficult to solve for me.

Instead of adding 1 TSQLConnection object to my data module, I added 3 of them. One for each dbms. When I want to connect, I assign it to the SQLConnection property of my TSQLDataset object - also found on the data module. Before I open the connection, I change only a few properties of the relevant TSQLConnection object, i.e. only the Params.Values. This way, you end up with a more stable application. The memory used by the TSQLConnection and TSQLDataset objects is freed when the data module is freed.

It means that I only use the Data.DBXOdbc unit when I want to connect to MS Access. For Oracle, I use the Oracle driver included in Delphi. And for Sqlite, I use the Sqlite driver. The main thing is that I can easily switch to another database ...